# 2FA Rest API in KeyClock

Tags: node.js, authentication, keycloak, google-2fa

I'm trying using keycloak for 2FA integration. Does keycloak support rest api for 2FA. If Yes, Please provide provide an api documentation and example. If it doesn't support, are there other ways 2FA in nodejs.

Tried and Refered many blogs but not get it.